# QT yaml-cpp Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, yaml-cpp

i am new on programming in windows and in QT.

I started a QT project and want include yaml-cpp 0.30

Now i have different problems. First i wanted to build the lib with cmake and Visualstudio but i am not sure if i did this right.

I start Cmake and build with VS2010 compiler. Then i load the file

build\CMakeFiles\2.8.11.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerCXX.vcxproj in VS 2010 but i cant build this or dont know how.

And how i integrate this build lib inside QTCreator?

Or i have the possibility to build all inside QTCREATOR?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

CMake will build a Visual Studio solution (a `.sln` file); you don't need to go into the `CMakeFiles` directory to find it. There should be a solution file in the top `build` directory.

Comment: hello, sry for my late answer. I dont have a .sln file in my build direction only 3 folders (Cmake Test Util) and CmakeCache.txt.